# The use of T[] as a template parameter

Tags: c++

I've recently stumbled upon the use of `unique_ptr<T[]>`, where I understand that the aim is to delete the pointer with `delete[]`.

What puzzles me is that `unique_ptr<T[3]>` is instead invalid (correct me if I'm wrong).

What is the type of T[] in the template? How is it different from T[3]? These are arrays, so shouldn't they be the same? Is there any other use of T[] as a type in templates?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`T[]` is a type. It's the type "array of unknown bound of `T`". It is an incomplete type.

`T[3]` is also a type. It's the type "array of 3 `T`". It is a different type from `T[]`, just like `int` and `double` are different types.

The `default_delete` template is specialized partially for incomplete arrays of the form `T[]`. However, the complete-array types like `T[3]` are forbidden, since that would be very confusing: the `unique_ptr` cannot tell how long your array is, since it only handles the array through a pointer to its first element.

(There are technical details in the mechanics: The specialization `default_delete<T[3]>` isn't actively prohibited, but since its call operator expects a `T(*)[3]`, it will generally not match the pointer that comes from the `unique_ptr`, and even if the call were well-formed, a `delete` expression on such a pointer is not allowed (= has undefined behaviour). You "cannot delete arrays" if you will, you can only "delete[] arrays via size-erased pointers".)

Note that the `make_unique` function template is actively deleted for complete array types.

Curiously, for `make_shared` the committee went down a different route and *allows* complete array types. To do so, `shared_ptr<T[N]>` has a precondition that you only construct it from a matching `new T[N]` (though that's not checkable in general). (I've never quite understood why that was a good idea.)

Comment: "However, the complete-array types like `T[3]` are forbidden" -- Do you mean ill-formed, or do you mean they have UB? They are accepted by libstdc++ and by libc++.

Comment: @hvd: I added some explanation; it's a bit complicated.

Comment: Ah, they have UB. "a `delete` expression on such a pointer is not well-formed" -- That part's not right. It's well-formed (defined in [defns.well.formed] as "constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable semantic rules, and the One Definition
Rule") but has UB: it falls under [expr.delete]p2 "[...] a null pointer
value, a pointer to a non-array object [...] or a pointer to a subobject [...] If not, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Kerrek SB Thank you. I never realized that arrays of unknown bound were actually a type. Are there other use cases? Do arrays of unknown bound exist also in C90 or where they introduced later? (Meta: should I post a new question?)

Comment: @CostantinoGrana: A typical thing to do is to have `extern int a[];` in a header and define `int a[N];` in the source file. This is perhaps an interesting example of how it's possible to have glvalues of incomplete type, but not variable definitions. The definition of `a` *completes* the type of `a`. There are also incomplete object types that can never be completed,  e.g. `T(*)[]`.

Comment: `make_shared` doesn't erase the size.

Comment: @T.C.: Oh, that's right, I misremembered -- `shared_ptr<U[N]>` is actually allowed, and its constructor from `U*` has a precondition.